# automatic glossary generation using Sublime Text 2 with LatexTools

Tags: latex

I am using Sublime Text 2 with LatexTools and it doesn't run makeglossaries automatically when i enter Ctrl-B to build within the editor. Tried to see if I could get Dr. Andre's obsoleted approach at http://drlog.andregoerres.de/make-sublime-text-2-automatically-compile-glossaries/ to work, but ran into problems with the makePDF.py trying to pull the engine out of the cmd variable setup in LaTeX.sublime-build.

Is there a recommended way to get this working? It seems like it might be a good feature out-of-the-box.

thanks!

Comment: not really an answer, but I got past this by installing the LaTeXing package and changing the LatexTools !TEX declarations at the top of the pages to use the new key/value notation.

Comment: just an aside, but if you decide to go with LaTeXing you might want to move up to Sublime Text 3.